# Drag Files From ListView

Tags: c#, webforms

It seemed farily straight forward learning how to process files dropped onto a ListView control. But I can't seem to find anything about dragging files **FROM** the ListView control.

To complicate things, the ListView control is displaying an FTP directory. So I don't want to actually download the files until I confirm they have been dropped on a window that will accept them.

I know that it's possible to provide the actual data for a drag-and-drop operation only after the drop has taken place. But I'm having trouble finding anything about doing this from a ListView control using C# and Webforms.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: i know how to do it in native code; you have to construct a fill an IDataObject with all the formats you support. Since the files will be coming from an artibrary data store (i.e. they're not actual files) you'll have to be passing them as IStreams. i know somewhere .NET has a nice object that implements IDataObject.

Comment: Yes, I've also done something similar in the past with C++/MFC using CDataObject. I did find a DataObject class in .NET, but it has no events, which would be necessary to respond to requests for the data. A nice little example would be perfect, but I'm just not finding anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best link I've found on this issue yet is at [Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/04/creating-something-from-nothing-asynchronously-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net-improved.aspx).

He starts by saying "This code [...] and is specifically targeted at scenarios where an application wants to allow the user to drag an element to a folder and create a file (or files) dynamically on the drop/paste. The standard .NET APIs for drag-and-drop don't support this scenario [...]"

Wow, that's the answer. For all the problems I have with C# and .NET, I run into yet another obstacle. He does have some code to workaround this. I'll be checking that out.